# Getting rid of an offset that doesn't want to leave

Tags: html, css

I have some nested divs, some of which are supposed to display as a table because it makes my life easier, but one of the innermost divs is being given a 16px offset from the top and I can't get rid of it.

The HTML:

```
<div class="waiting">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="time">
            09:55
        </div>
        <div class="customer">
            <div class="cust-name">
                Ana Ling 
            </div>
            <div class="cust-deets">
                Female, 51
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            TODO
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.waiting {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    height:60px;
    color:black;
    background:rgb(134, 145, 149);
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;
}

    .waiting .table-row {
        display:table-row;
    }

        .waiting .time {
            display:table-cell;
            background:rgb(125, 134, 139);
            width:60px;
            padding:20px 15px;
            font-size:14px;
            color:rgb(65, 73, 75);
        }

        .waiting .customer {
            display:table-cell;
            padding:0;
            color:rgb(27, 35, 38);
            padding:10px 15px;
        }

            .waiting .customer .cust-name {
                font-size:18px;
                margin-top:-16px;                /* Undoing IE offset */
                vertical-align:top;              /* Come on stupid IE */
            }

            .waiting .customer .cust-deets {
                font-size:14px;
                margin:0;
            }

        .waiting .menu {
            display:table-cell;
        }
```

To be specific, it is the `cust-name` div that is being offset by an unnecessary 16px from the top, and neither negative margins nor manually reassigning the top position does anything.  I even tried changing the value in the console within the box model, but that 16px just keeps re-asserting itself regardless of what value I change it to.  I've also tried setting the position to relative before assigning the top value, but that just made the height of the element bigger.

I am trying to do this in IE11 and this website will only every be viewed on IE11, so if you even just have a hacky solution that only works for IE11, please give it to me!

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion, try making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and posting it here :) With HTML/CSS questions, it's difficult for potential responders to figure out what's going without seeing the final product, so most people will just go to another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. You want to show tabular data but you want to avoid using an actual table, presumably because "tables are bad". Tables are considered bad form for *layout*, it's true, but you're showing structured data. Start by making it a table and style it from there, save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: This fixed it!  I was trying to avoid using a table because it's not _really_ tabular data, but I guess it's close enough.  It's interesting, shouldn't table tags and divs told to display as table tags behave in the same way on regular screens (as opposed to screen readers and other such things where the semantics matter)?

Comment: That's a good question! One I'm afraid I'm unqualified to answer :)
Looking at the HTML it looks like it should work.

Comment: I made up a pretty basic version of what you were trying to do, to compare the div approach with the table approach. From this JSFiddle it looks like both are certainly do-able, but the styles differ (I reckon it's because the DIVs never inherit the browser styles for a table).
https://jsfiddle.net/3x8j4xk0/

Comment: Fascinating!  I wonder what the reasoning behind that is.  Probably just one of those problems with backwards compatibility.  Anyway, it's good to know going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Add a vertical align to your `.waiting .customer` and remove the padding top as well (and remember to remove the negative margin from .cust-name).

```
.waiting .customer {
     display:table-cell;
     color:rgb(27, 35, 38);
     padding: 0 15px 10px;
     vertical-align: top;
}
```